# namespace error in c#

Tags: c#, namespaces

I've a class in namespace `Inventory_Software.BL` with name **BL**, and I want to access this class in `Inventory_Software.PL.Item_Master` class, but despite of using syntax 
`using Inventory_Software.BL` before **namespace** name in that class, I'm getting an error:

```
'Inventory_Software.BL' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'
```

whenever I try to initialized **BL** class with syntax:

```
BL businesslayer = new BL();
```

Could anyone please tell me why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you're in a world of pain when you start give a class the same name as a namespace. Just don't do it - rename either your class or your namespace.

You probably *can* work round it with suitable using directives, but is it really worth that much pain? (I personally wouldn't use "BL" as a name for either a namespace or a class, nor would I use an underscore within a name; but that's a different matter.)

Eric Lippert has a [series of four blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/namespaces/) posts about this - "Do not name a class the same as its namespace":

- [Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx)
- [Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/11/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-two.aspx)
- [Part 3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/15/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-three.aspx)
- [Part 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/18/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-four.aspx)

Comment: All four parts are here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/namespaces/

Comment: @Eric: Doh - hadn't noticed the rest, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

since its Inventory_Software.BL, you have initialized a namespace inside a namespace, instead, do this:

```
Inventory_Software.BL businessLayer = new Inventory_Software.Bl();
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can't tell the difference between whether you're referencing the namespace or they type. Either change the namespace to not be **BL** or change the name of the class to be something other than **BL**. Maybe call it **BusinessLayer** instead...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see if you have a `namespace` called `BL` and a class called `BL`.  If so, you'll need to use the full reference to the class or change the name of your class/namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create an object of BL. But BL is not a class. It is just a namespace.

You can create object of a class by specifying the name of the class. In your code, you must be having something as

public class NameofYourClass

{

// your methods here

}

So, in this case, you will be able to write

```
NameofYourClass yourObject = new NameofYourClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a class Inventory_Software.BL.BL and you're trying to access it from scope of Inventory_Software.PL.Item_Master.

As expected an unqualified name BL would resolve to 'Inventory_Software.BL' and not 'Inventory_Software.BL.BL'.

You could do away with by adding either of following usings

using Inventory_Software.BL;
OR simply
using BL;